# Redefining \section outputs the equivalent of an additional \section{*} before the TOC

Tags: macros, sectioning, optional-arguments

When I redefine the `\section` command, an additional section with title "*" is created before the table of contents, as if I had inserted a `\section{*}` before the table of content, which I never did. Here is the minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip,lipsum}
\let\oldsection\section
\def\section#1{\oldsection{#1}} % CREATES ADDITIONAL GHOST SECTION???

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{I am a section}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of what I am getting at the bottom.

What I have tried:

1. Using `\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\oldsection{#1}}` gives exactly the same problem.
2. Omitting the argument as in `\def\section{\oldsection}` does not create the same problem, but I need to pass the argument for what I need to do.

(What I need to do in the grander scheme of things: I want to redefine `\def\section#1{\clearevenpage\twocolumn[\oldsection{#1}]}` so that sections start on even pages and span the whole page in a twocolumn document. However, the unexpected behaviour seems wholly unrelated to what I am trying to achieve here.)

[image: output with the extra section]

---

EDIT: For anyone wondering,  `\clearevenpage` mentioned above is defined as

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\clearevenpage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page
    \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. Within the `article` document class, `\tableofcontents` issues `\section*{\contentsname}`. Note the `*`.
2. `\section` is defined not to take any arguments by default. Whaaa?! In fact, it passes the argument capturing and star checking over to other macros.

So your (re)definition of `\section` to take a singular argument is bound to take whatever is passed as the first argument as its *only* argument... and as you've seen, this is a problem when that first argument is a `*` (like with `\tableofcontents`).

Instead of your simple redefinition, you would have to either intervene in a different location (not `\section` but somewhere deeper in the bowels of subsidiary macros called by `\section`) or condition on the choices offered by the default `\section` from the start. This latter option is easier and more comprehensible.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{xparse}% Use this if your LaTeX distribution is not up-to-date.

\newcommand{\clearevenpage}{\clearpage}% Or whatever you have \clearevenpage defined as.

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \clearevenpage
  \twocolumn[%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {\oldsection*{#3}}% \section*[.]{..}
      {\IfValueTF{#2}
        {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
        {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
      }%
  ]
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{I am a section}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent answer! For anyone wondering, I will edit the question to specify the definition of `\clearevenpage` in case anyone finds it useful.